# Reading and Writing from a txt file

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm trying to read and write from a txt file using C#. At the moment, I'm writing a program that reads the names in a list, shows them to the user, asks for another name, and then adds that one to the list. The reading is fine, but there's some problems with the writing.

The code compiles fine using CSC, and it executes fine, but after I type the name to add and hit enter, I get a window popping up saying

> FileIO.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.

Any idea what the problem is?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Hello1
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        int lines = File.ReadAllLines("Name.txt").Length;
        string[] stringArray = new string[lines + 1];
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Name.txt");
        for(int i = 1;i <=lines;i++){
            stringArray[i-1] = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        for (int i = 1;i <=stringArray.Length;i++){
            Console.WriteLine(stringArray[i-1]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a name to add to the list.");
        stringArray[lines] = Console.ReadLine();
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Name.txt", true)){
            writer.WriteLine(stringArray[lines]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `using` statement also for the reader. `using(var reader = new StreamReader("Name.txt")){...}`

Comment: Close the stream before you reopen it to write. Better use ’using’ statement

Comment: Why are you using `File.ReadAllLines`, then *just* taking the length, then reading it all in again? There are *much* simpler ways of achieving this...

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the exception because you are not closing your `reader`, Just place `reader.Close();` after reading your file to Array.

Even better is to use `using` statement, since `StreamReader` uses `IDisposable` interface, this would ensure closing of the stream as well as its disposal.

```
string[] stringArray = new string[lines + 1];
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Name.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++)
    {
        stringArray[i - 1] = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Just a **side note**:

you are use `File.ReadAllLines` just to get `Length`???, you can fillup your array like:

```
string[] stringArray = File.ReadAllLines("Name.txt");
```

instead of going through `StreamReader`.

Answer (score 2):

How about we simplify this a bit:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("Name.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a name to add to the list.");
var name = Console.ReadLine();
File.AppendLine("Name.txt", name):
```

Now you're not dealing with the IO at all because you're leaving it to the framework by leveraging those static methods wholly.

Comment: Why bother reading the file to start with? You're ignoring the string array afterwards...

Comment: @Jon, can you just Console.WriteLine the entire file with maybe File.ReadAllText?

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that it was dumping that to the console - sorry. Note that your code will currently fail on the last iteration - you want `<` rather than `<=`. Better, use `foreach`. Even better, use `foreach` with `File.ReadLines`...

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for that error. It was originally `1` based and I was trying to make it `0` based. And yes, you're right, let's just use the `foreach` on `ReadLines` - let me edit.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to ensure that you learn of any exceptions at the top level of a console application:

```
public class Hello1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            // whatever
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception!);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.Write("Press ENTER to exit: ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you'll know *why* the application had to close.

Additionally, you need to have your `StreamReader` in a `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read all lines from a file into an array, you can simply use:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Name.txt");
```

And use that array.

Answer (score -2):

Use the reader.ReadToEnd function like this and don't forget to close the reader when you finish.:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Name.txt");
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
```

The reason you get that exception is because you don't close the reader after reading. So you can't write to it without first calling the Close(); method.

You can also use the using statement instead of closing it like this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Name.txt")){
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
};
```

Comment: You should use a `using` statement - and I think you've missed the point of the question, which is to read the file line by line.

Comment: Not closing the reader doesn't result in an exception, you just leak a resource.

Comment: Thanks Jon, added that too! Servy he is trying to write to it when its still open.

Comment: @Dimo: You're still using `ReadToEnd`, which goes against what the OP wants - and you've got a spare semi-colon for no reason.